# Angular 7 PWA - 1min first load times or more

Tags: angular, performance, amazon-s3, angular7, ionic4

I have a problem with the first load time of my angular 7/Ionic 4 page it takes significantly higher time .

If a user enters the page first time, even with good internet connection, he will see for up to a minute a white page until the content finally loads. Since the page uses PWA functionality and a serviceworker, later loading times are around 1 second, which is OK.

The source code is quite big (around 14mb) and integrates many modules. Unfortunately I wont be able to reduce it significantly, but I doubt this is  the only issue here. Because of integrating the page as PWA I had to put everything to **prefetch** in the ngsw-config file, which might have an influence. The page is packed by the angular packer with the --prod flag.

Looking at the network tab in the console, I managed to identify it is mainly the main.a234324.js file (around 5mb), created by the angular packer, which takes so long to load and prevents the page from further initialising. The page is hosted on a s3 and integrates cloudfront.

I've seen various advice and tutorials on how to improve page speed, but so far none helped.

Did anyone encounter (and solve) a similar issue? Why can one .js file take so long to load?

Comment: Really hard to tell without knowing how your project is setup, there is too many variables that can cause performance issues. For example it could be you are loading large modules on load, instead of lazy loading modules.

Comment: If you run the performance profiler in the chrome devtools for the initial load of your app, and upload the results here, I may be able to help diagnose further. Also check this out: https://blog.logrocket.com/better-development-with-chrome-developer-tools-78b7d688438a/

Comment: I agree that it's hard to say. But even if it is far from optimization and surely not recommendable, loading the whole bundle of 15 mb should take only a few seconds with a good internet connection. But the main.js loads with less than 100kb/s. Maybe it get's parsed some sort of?

Comment: @Reactgular thanks, I might try to reconstruct the issue that way. However my question is not focused on why the bundle size got so big, but why it gets downloaded so slowly. So regarding your metaphor, I'm not asking why the train is so heavy, but why the rails seem to be blocked :-)

Comment: There are lots of potential reasons why your app might not be performing well. Unfortunately, you’ll have to do the heavy lifting to figure it out. Let us know once you’ve found the issue and can’t figure out how to fix it.

Comment: I figured, a big problem is the usage of barrel files. Everything they export get's written to the main.js file, which is drastically bloated because of this. I'll continue to look into it.